# Bringing in data for current month and year

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to bring in data for the current month (5/1-5/31) and do the same for every month coming forward. Where I use the following code, it's not working. If I change it to >= it brings, in data all the way from 2016. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
 WHERE [20200512 Daily Deposits].[Date] = MONTH(getdate())
 AND [20200512 Daily Deposits].[Date] = YEAR(getdate())
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server:

```
where [20200512 Daily Deposits].[Date] >= datefromparts(year(getdate(), month(getdate(), 1) and
      [20200512 Daily Deposits].[Date] < dateadd(month, 1, datefromparts(year(getdate(), month(getdate(), 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `.[Date]` column is actual a date type then you can just do..

```
 WHERE MONTH([20200512 Daily Deposits].[Date]) = MONTH(getdate())
 AND YEAR([20200512 Daily Deposits].[Date]) = YEAR(getdate())
```

If they are not date data types then please edit your question and show some sample data with the data types explained.